# Construct lists from existing lists at compile time

Tags: d

I have a global list of items (each with a few properties) in a module of my program. It's immutable and statically defined in the code, so no worries there.

For instance let's say I have vegetables, which are just an alias defining them to an immutable tuple with `name` (string), `code` (ubyte) and `price` (ushort).

I'd like to be able to access those either by `name` or by `code` ; so I thought since the list of vegetables is known at compile-time, I could probably construct associative arrays with references to these vegetables (so string=>vegetable and ubyte=>vegetable)

Here's the kind of thing I am trying to achieve :

```
static struct instructions
{
    // list of Veggies

    immutable instr[] list = [
        Veggie("Potato" , 0xD0, 2),
        Veggie("Carrot" , 0xFE, 5),
    ];


    // genByCode and genByName being pure functions that get CTFE'd
    // and return the desired associative array

    immutable instr[ubyte]  byCode = genByCode(list);
    immutable instr[string] byName = genByName(list);


    // overloaded function returns the right Veggie

    instr get(string name) const
    { return byName[name]; }
    instr get(ubyte  code) const
    { return byCode[code]; }

}
```

With those generator functions (separated for clarity) of the form

```
pure instr[ubyte] genByCode(immutable Veggie[] list)
{
    instr[ubyte] res;
    foreach (i ; list)
        res[i.code] = i;
    return res;
}
```

I spent quite some time messing around but I couldn't it to work. Of course it would be trivial to construct at runtime, but clearly it should be possible to do it at compile time.

At first I thought it was an issue of mutability, so I tried marking everything (vegetables and vegetable lists) as immutable (as they should be anyway), but then I ran into issues which I think regard immutable tuples, and feel too lost to keep going.

Could I get help from someone with a clearer overview of the mechanisms at play here ? Thanks !

Comment: The problem here is that the compiler doesn't know how to actually create associative arrays at compile time... the binary layout is delegated to the runtime library, so the compiler literally doesn't know how to share the data... tbh I'd just do it at runtime.

Comment: `list` is not known at compile-time.  Did I understand you correctly when you asserted it is?  `enum` is a compile-time known variable, `immutable` is a run-time  variable that simply cannot be changed.

Comment: `static immutable` actually does work at compile time in most, if not all contexts on newer (this year at least) versions of the compiler. So that part is ok.

Answer (score 0):

The data is already there, no need to construct a compile-time associative array.

Just iterate over it statically:

```
static auto get(int code)(){
    static foreach(veggie; list)
        static if(veggie.code == code)
            return veggie;
}

...

void main(){
    writeln(instructions.get!0xD0);
}
```

It may be slower than access through a hash map, but that's the life of CTFE.

To make sure it evaluates at compile time, you can use this:

```
template get(int code){
    static foreach(veggie; list)
        static if(veggie.code == code)
            alias get = veggie;
}
```

Comment: You can actually do slightly better by making a switch instead of a static if. The compiler may optimize a switch into a binary search or jump table, depending on the content.

Comment: Even when it doesn't actually generate code but is interpreted at compile time?

Comment: Oh, maybe not there since it is a different template argument every time, it code generates each time anyway. But if you reused template arguments, even at compile time the more optimized implementation might be worth it since it would get to reuse that code. (the current ctfe impl is outright awful though so idk if it realizes that)

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't explain myself very well. If I understand what you mean, it's a question of compile-time data access, but that's not what I'm after. I need a hashmap for runtime, and I thought I'd be nice to build it at compile time rather than do it by hand or build it on runtime (which is what I do currently, as M. Ruppe suggested, and since it's not a very big dataset anyway)

Comment: Oh well, I guess @AdamD.Ruppe 's suggestion with a generated switch would be a good answer then :p